# For a merkle proof, how can I pass a Hex value into my solidity contract when it is expecting a bytes32 array?

Tags: javascript, solidity, merkle-tree

I have a functional merkle root/proof system that works flawlessly on etherscan. For example, I pass the proof that looks like this into the bytes32[] field, and it mints smoothly as long as the account is on the allowlist

```
0x7af845e970b0229e08846bfb99009787b76dcd04013f254aaeb2d9a088498318,0x1f957db768cd7253fad82a8a30755840d536fb0ffca7c5c73fe9d815b1bc2f2f,0x924862b314bd38813a325167aca7caee16318f07303bd8e9f81bbe5808575fbf,0xe5076a139576746fd34a0fd9c21222dc274a909421fcbaa332a5af7272b6dcb1,0x148c730f8169681c1ebfb5626eb20af3d2351445463a1fdc5d0b116c62dc58c8,0xf6a007a810573434e71c7550cc4458160fe5b66c03d050e6b5c4e400c131d82a
```

When I go to call the mint function via Ethers api, I cannot find a way to pass the proof into the function successfully. I'm getting the hex proof and passing that into the mint function like so:

```
const hashedAddress = keccak256(whitelistAddresses[1])
const proof = whitelistTree.getHexProof(hashedAddress)
const mintResp = await contract.mint(quantity, kdaAddress, proof);
```

The constant "proof" when I just do a simple console.log(proof) returns an object that looks like this

`["0x7af845e970b0229e08846bfb99009787b76dcd04013f254aaeb2d9a088498318","0x1f957db768cd7253fad82a8a30755840d536fb0ffca7c5c73fe9d815b1bc2f2f","0x924862b314bd38813a325167aca7caee16318f07303bd8e9f81bbe5808575fbf","0xe5076a139576746fd34a0fd9c21222dc274a909421fcbaa332a5af7272b6dcb1","0x148c730f8169681c1ebfb5626eb20af3d2351445463a1fdc5d0b116c62dc58c8","0xf6a007a810573434e71c7550cc4458160fe5b66c03d050e6b5c4e400c131d82a"]`

No matter what I try to convert this array to, I cannot get my mint function to accept it, I just get gas estimation errors. **My question is: How do I pass my proof into the contract call?**

`const mintResp = await contract.mint(quantity, kdaAddress, proof);`

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce your issue based on what you've shared so far. The snippet that you shared seems to pass the proof to the contract correctly, however it is possible that you're incorrectly generating the root, or the proof, or that there is another issue... You can find an inspiration in my [code](https://github.com/petr-hejda/solidity-merkle-airdrop) that I wrote few months ago. It does exactly what I'm assuming is your goal - generating merkle tree in JS, passing its root to Solidity, generating a proof  of a specific leaf in JS and then validating this proof in Solidity.

Answer (score 0):

As i understanding the problem is how to pass byte array parameter to the contract call. I am going to share with my past project's code which is very similar task that you want to do.

I am assuming that you successfully generated root hash and updated the smart contract.

let say we have an array of addresses on javascript like

```
let whitelist = ["0x0000....2", "0x0000....1", "0x0000....5"];
```

I am going to use two libraries

```
import { MerkleTree } from 'merkletreejs';
import keccak256 from 'keccak256';
```

First i get leaves from whitelist

```
const leaves = whitelist.map(x => keccak256(x));
```

Then create the merkleproof

```
const merkle = new MerkleTree(leaves, keccak256, {sortPairs : true});
```

Then create proof for selected address

```
const proof = merkle.getHexProof(keccak256(walletAddress.toString()))
```

Remember, walletAddress should be inside the whitelist array. You have to check it before doing all the process above.

And finally call the contract

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(NFTContract, ABI, signer);
const call = await contract.mintPresale(1,proof,options);
```

If you dont know what options variable is then;

```
const options = {value: ethers.utils.parseEther((Number(whitelistPrice) * nftCount).toString())}
```

It simply add a value to transaction. Also it can be used for determining gasPrice and gasLimit.

I hope that answers your question :)

EDIT

I also mention my contract parameters

```
function mintPresale(uint numberOfTokens, bytes32[] calldata _merkleProof) public payable
```